# Always-on VPN sends no traffic

Tags: vpn

I've set up a L2TP/IPSec VPN server with pre-shared keys, and everything works fine when I connect to the VPN manually.

However, when it's set to be the *always-on VPN*, everything changed. It seemd that no traffic was sent to the Internet anymore. If I opened a URL, the browser would return `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Is there anything wrong with my configuration of my phone or the VPN server?

I'm running android 4.4.4 with a recent CM nightly build.

Comment: After upgrading to lollipop, always-on vpn just works... FYI

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is an bug in android kitkat listet as  Issue 64819.

it says:

> **Android 4.4 VPN: DNS request packets' source IP address is always private address**
>
> A packet capture shows that the DNS packets are sent out of the public
>   interface, as expected, but source IP address is the VPN-assigned
>   private address, which is not publicly routable.
>
> This issues does not occur on Android 4.3.

see here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64819